# "Macintosh HD" no longer shows up in Finder on Lion

Tags: terminal, finder, macos

How do I get to the Macintosh HD, or the root folder, from Finder in Lion? It no longer appears in the favorites section.

I know I can open it from Terminal, but I want to do it in Finder easily like I could in 10.6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disks have been removed from the Finder sidebar by default, however you can easily reenable these.  In Finder go to File > Preferences and then to the Sidebar tab.  There you can choose what gets displayed in your sidebar.

[image: Finder Preferences]

Comment: Yes, but Macintosh HD isn't in that list.

Comment: It's included under Hard disks in the devices section. You can then Command + Drag the Macintosh HD from Devices to Favorites in the Finder window if you would like after turning Hard disks on.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> is how I do it.  You can also use the "Go" menu in Finder and choose the "Computer" option.